# Vue how to autofocus v-dialog (popup) when I open it on btn?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I open popup, he don't have focus on. I need to press anything inside of window and after that my esc btn will work (for closing window). Any suggest how to focus on popup immediately after button open it?

```
<v-dialog @keydown.esc="cancel" v-model="show" persistent max-width="750px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline"> New Exclusion </span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
            <v-container fluid>
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" md="5">
                  <v-switch
                    v-model="percentOrAmountSwitch"
                    :label="percentOrAmountLabel"
                    :color="colorTheme.toggle"
                  ></v-switch>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="2"></v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="5">
                  <v-checkbox
                    label="Expiration Date"
                    v-model="expDate"
                    v-on:change="hideShow"
                  >
                  </v-checkbox>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" md="5">
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="percentOrAmount"
                    :label="percentOrAmountLabel"
                    dense
                    :rules="percentOrAmountRules"
                    required
                    :prefix="flatDollar"
                    :suffix="percentBased"
                    :color="colorTheme.textField"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="2"></v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="5">
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    v-model="date"
                    v-if="expDate"
                    min="1960-01-01"
                  />
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
```

Comment: You can write a event on button @click="doSomething()" and into your doingSomething function you can do that

Comment: I think you should remove the `@keydown.esc="cancel"` as this is handled automatically by default, by the Dialog component.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `ref` to some input field, for example `text` on the modal, then focus on that element in modal in the mounted hook and use $vm.nextTick() so that you're sure the element is present in the DOM:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.text.focus());
}
```

Comment: I tried as you write there but it did not work. A get error message :   "Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Vue'" And I don't have any idea how can I handle that problem.

Comment: @Stefan Djordjevic hey mate, can you give more context, maybe some snippet or more code so I can reproduce your problem. Are you using TS?

Comment: hey mate, I just added small part of code I can not put all code it is to long and stack don't allowed me. I don't you TypeScript if you ask me that, I use regular JavaScript. Ofc I did not add closing tangs and staff in this code that I just added. 
In the buttom I import mounted this and so one but it did not work.

Comment: it's a simple dialog when you press esc he should disappear. But because dialog is not in focus I need to click on it and after that esc btn works. Soo confusing..

Comment: ok, in order to use `focus()` you need to have some element on your modal that can receive focus. Then `ref` that element and mounted hook in modal should work.

Comment: I tried to put ref as input attribute ref="text" and in  mount I call this ref, did not work. 
And also I tried to give v-dialog ref attribute and call in mount, did not work.
Input can receive focus?
 `<input
                    ref="text"
                    type="date"
                    v-model="date"
                    v-if="expDate"
                    min="1960-01-01"


mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.text.focus());
}`
Like that?

Comment: ok, I see now you are using vuetify, sorry never used that library but as I can see from their documentation event on esc is already implemented